# What should I do if I named a Model in Rails 3 plural?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, has-many, plural

I created a model called UserHasMessages based on some SO postings.  I think this seems to be creating some challenges for me:

- How do I reference it with `has_many`?  Should I use has_many `:user_has_messageses`?
- How do I do joins?  I have tried User.joins(:user_has_messages) and it is sad :(

**Question:**

Should I somehow change the name to UserHasMessage, and if so, how?

If I keep as plural, how do I handle these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a new migration

```
rails g migration rename_user_has_messages
```

inside it you write:

```
class RenameUserHasMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :user_has_messages, :user_messages
  end

  def self.down
    rename_table :user_messages, :user_has_messages
  end
end
```

(the table is always plural)

Run the migration.

Rename your file from `user_has_messages.rb` to `user_message.rb`, and rename your class from `UserHasMessages` to `UserMessage`.

Done :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the same syntax you use with legacy tables:

```
class OtherClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_has_messages, :class_name => 'UserHasMessages'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid class names that end with an S, like the devil avoids holy water. The name UserHasMessages is a very poor choice. You do not create a db table to check for something. Instead, you have a User model, a Message model and a UserMessage model. Then, if you want to check user messages, you just create a method that does that. The association should be :

```
User has many messages through user_messages
```

and you would get user messages like current_user.messages .

I highly advise you to change your design to the one i described :)

Comment: @SpyrosP...btw, will this help fix the :joins issues I've been having?

Comment: definitely. If you do it like this, you would not need join since activerecord will automatically do it for you.

Comment: I wouldn't say avoid class names ending with an S, but do avoid plural names.